# Should it be "substituted in for" or "substituted for"?

Tags: prepositions

The past action that I'm trying to describe is: one meal that has been replaced with a different meal. Which is more correct:

1. "He substituted one meal for a different meal."

or

2. "He substituted one meal in for a different meal."

Answer (score 1):

1. is correct.

But we wouldn't normally repeat the word 'meal'.

> He substituted one meal for another

is more idiomatic.

You could also say, "He **replaced** one meal **with** another" but it's less furtive than 'substituted'. A waiter might replace: an assassin would substitute. – Old Brixtonian 57 secs ago